# Strapi image not rendering on my _slug.vue page using Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi

I can't seem to get my strapi images to render on my _slug.vue page. I was able to render title and content from strapi on the page. When I take out the image code, the page renders just fine with the article title and content.

```
    <div class="article__container">
      <h1 class="article__title">{{ articles.title }}</h1>
      <img :src="api_url + articles.image.url" class="article__img" />
      <div
        class="article__content"
        v-html="$md.render(articles.content || 'No description provided')"
      ></div>
      <div class="article__side-bar"><p>Sidebar</p></div>
    </div>


<script>
import articleQuery from "~/apollo/queries/article/Article";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
     api_url: process.env.strapiBaseUri  
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    articles: {},
    
  }),
  apollo: {
    articles: {
      prefetch: true,
      query: articleQuery,
      variables() {
        return { slug: this.$route.params.slug };
      },
      update: data => data.articles[0]
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to have the `head` method in the page and use variable there

- you do have access to the `this` and you could have

```
head() {
  return: {
    title: this.title 
    meta: [
        { 
          hid: `${this.title}-page-description`,
          description: `${this.article.descriptioin}`
        },
     ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry  for the answer before (i was thinking somewhere else)

this is what you could do

- create a computed property where you modify the actual URL of the images

```
computed: {
   updatedArticleImage() {
    return this.articles.image.url.split('/uploads/').join('YOUR STRAPI URL/uploads/')
   }
}
```

and use that as the actual content to add to your image `:src`